A movie set in 30s or 40s about a boy who leads the police to a murderer
I've seen a chunk of a movie during a bus trip some time ago but don't know what the title is. 
The movie is set in 30's or 40's (judging from the clothes the characters are wearing). I think it's was made around 2010, definitely American and starring semi-known actors (I remember seeing some of them in other movies and shows playing minor roles).
The things I remember from it:
There's a young boy (around 12 years old) that's caught by the police, I think he might've been caught stealing or he was brought in because he was wandering around. The boy is dirty, scared and sickly, looks like he's homeless. I think later on they find bruises on his body. 
He's not talking at first when the police officers try to question him at the station but then he tells them that he escaped from a bad place/imprisonment. The police officers are probably detectives because they don't wear uniforms but suits and "gangster" type hats. There's one detective (male) that takes interest in the boy and his story and talks with him quite a bit when they're still at the police station. I think the boy later stated he was sexualy abused by the person he escaped from.
Detectives don't believe the boy at first but then he leads them to a house in a middle of nowhere, where they find blood and stuff that implicates someone was held prisoner in there. Eventually they start digging in the ground next to the house and find several bodies (they're small so it's implicated they're children). I don't remember correctly, they might've found the bodies in a well or inside the house, I just remember the lead detective having an "Oh my god..." moment after discovering the tragedy and it was definitely outside. The scenes at the murderer's house took place during a day and it was sunny.
I don't remember anything more from it.

Changeling
You can read the detailed plot on Wikipedia here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeling_(film)
Actor Michael Kelly plays the detective, who listens to the boy's story.
Trailer:



From Wikipedia:

"Detective Ybarra (Kelly) travels to a ranch in Wineville, Riverside
  County, to arrange the deportation of 15-year-old Sanford Clark (Eddie
  Alderson) to Canada. The boy's uncle, Gordon Northcott (Harner), has
  fled after a chance encounter with Ybarra, who mentions his business
  there being a juvenile matter. Clark tells Ybarra that Northcott
  forced him to help kidnap and murder around twenty children, and
  identifies Walter as one of them. Jones tells Briegleb that Christine
  is in protective custody following a mental breakdown. Jones orders
  Clark's deportation, but Ybarra takes Clark to the murder site and
  tells him to dig where the bodies are buried. Clark hesitates, but
  soon uncovers body parts."

Here, you can watch the part where the boy tells his story to the detective:



